# Handle exceptions in Laravel Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, listener

I want to handle Exceptions in my Listener exactly in `handle()` method

```php
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param DocumentGenerated $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(DocumentGenerated $event)
{
    $data = $event->data;
    $this->generateDoc($data);
}
```

After I read the documentation I found that the handle() method of the listener should return false to stop the event propagation.

I changed the return type of the handle() method from void to boolean and tried returning false but it didn't stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exceptions by catching the exceptions and returning false. Example:

```
  /**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param DocumentGenerated $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(FirstPaymentScheduleCreated $event)
{
  try {
    $data = $event->data;
    $this->generateDoc($data);

   }catch (Exception $e) {
    //Handle the exception
    return false; //stop event propagation
   }
    return true // allow event propagation
}
```